# PHP Geolocation clustering users into world zones

Tags: php, geolocation

The idea is to divide the entire world into zones with a grid. Each square in the grid will be a cluster. Based on the user latitude and longitude I need to check where the user location is in those clusters and put the user in it.

What I need to achieve is a way to cluster the users locations and to know which users are nearest to each other.

The idea of dividing the world in grids is only an option. If it's an easier way, well, much better. I know I can check the distance of two given users in many ways, but this is not what I am looking for. I need to create locations clusters and put each user in the relative cluster.

Does anyone know a script/api/way to achieve the above?

Any help is very appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Cluster analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) is a complex problem to which many solutions exist, depending on your needs and available information.

[*k*-means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means) is an algorithm in which you provide how many clusters you expect as initial parameter and the algorithm will cluster around that number. It's fast, but oftentimes doesn't lead to the best results and/or forces you to pick a number for *k* which you cannot make any guesses about.

[DBSCAN](http://staffwww.itn.liu.se/~aidvi/courses/06/dm/Seminars2011/DBSCAN%284%29.pdf) is an algorithm which creates clusters based on the distance between two locations and a cutoff radius you supply. It creates much better results than *k*-means, but is also significantly slower.

Beyond that there are many more algorithms available, all tweaked and optimized for different data models or use cases. There are no implementations of any in PHP that I'm aware of. What you really want for this is a database with GIS support, for instance PostgreSQL + [PostGIS](http://postgis.net). It's an excellent choice. There's a native [*k*-means extension](http://pgxn.org/dist/kmeans/) available for it. You can [hook it into R](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44851/using-pl-r-for-clustering-geometries), which has [many packages for all sorts of clustering algorithms](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Cluster.html).

If your dataset is large enough, that's the only viable route and will take some initial uphill battling for sure. Otherwise you're pretty much stuck with a simple rounding-coordinates-to-nearest-integer-and-count-them algorithm, which is simple to implement in PHP with virtually any database (but only gets you square grid-based clusters, not pretty).

There are of course many compromises possible to solve this using simple tools. Do simple grid-based clustering in the database to narrow down the dataset, then further cluster those remaining markers in PHP or Javascript on the client using weight-based algorithms. Or precalculate the whole thing every night using whatever slow method you have. But no implementation will be as good as something you can achieve using a decent GIS backend.

---

I had approached a similar problem a few years ago thinking it couldn't be that hard and eventually abandoning it, since with the tools I had available at the time it turns out it *is* hard. Your average PHP/MySQL combo gives you virtually nothing to work with to solve that problem sufficiently. Once you upgrade to the right tools, many more solutions suddenly become available to you. In my case that's currently PostGIS, R and [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org). Since any algorithm is either CPU or memory intensive or both, PHP is typically insufficient to implement it and a database without native GIS data types and functions makes your life unnecessarily difficult.

Comment: I am a little confused. K-means requires to know how many clusters. But how do I decide how many clusters? I mean, I only get the user latitude and longitude. The clusters is what I am looking to create after that. As for DBSCAN what the second location could be? Should I get the north pole and the south pole as the two locations? And when I ll get the user latitude and longitude how DBSCAN will understand the belonging cluster? This is all new for me and I am not getting it at all :/

Comment: Exactly. That's why *k*-means is pretty worthless for most applications. If your dataset is very uniformly spread out (gaussian noise for instance), it's useful. Otherwise not so much. DBSCAN must work on an entire *dataset*. It picks one point at random and "walks" over nearby points until it can't find any other nearby points anymore, then starts again elsewhere, thus forming clusters. I can really recommend you play around with R, it's an awesome environment to *visually* experiment with different algorithms to grok how they work.

Comment: You said "Otherwise you're pretty much stuck with a simple rounding-coordinates-to-nearest-integer-and-count-them algorithm, which is simple to implement in PHP with virtually any database (but only gets you square grid-based clusters, not pretty)." I think this is exaclty what I am looking for. Do you have any suggestion on this?

Comment: Basically: just round the lat/lon to the nearest integer (or fraction thereof) and `GROUP BY` that. Depending on what you need this for it may suffice, but it doesn't look pretty if you want "markers on a map".

Comment: @Php It's not impossible, but far from ideal. There's virtually no existing infrastructure for anything but the most rudimentary GIS operations in both PHP and MySQL. Can you point to an existing DBSCAN or similar implementation for MySQL? Doing it purely in PHP is often prohibitive since you need to transfer *all* data into memory first, which is unrealistic for large sets.

Comment: @Php I'm not talking about index types, I'm talking about *clustering algorithms*. Yes, because rounding is too simple, you want a better algorithm like, for instance, DBSCAN or something of comparable quality. Can you point to a pure MySQL implementation of it or of a feasible PHP implementation?

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you are asking for k-means or dB scan. Mysql has a spatial  extension and point data type. Hence you can simply  put the users in point column and use a query  where the points are within a  rectangle. I  have also wrote a quadkey php cluster  script based on monster curves. It's a quadtree often use in Oracle dB or other. You can write me an email or download my class from  phpclasses. The package name is hilbert curve. Here is an example of bing map tiling http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx.

Comment: Please elaborate on what problem exactly you can solve using your hilbert curve. It appears to me the OP is looking for a clustering algorithm to produce something along the lines of http://www.kiwicollection.com/search/map, I'm not sure your answer is going in the same direction.

Comment: Sure, you're explaining *tiling*. But tiling is not necessarily the same as *cluster analysis*. I have gone into a lot of detail in my answer, but all you say is "use a hilbert/monster/morton curve". That doesn't really help in understanding how to use it, what to use it for or what the result will look like.

Comment: I'm not an expert in clustering or R, but from what you're writing neither can I discern that you are. Client-side clustering is problematic because you need to transfer the *entire dataset* to the client, the same problem with just transferring it into PHP to cluster there. Try clustering a dataset of several million observations this way, it's very infeasible. That needs to happen in the database if at all possible. I'm genuinely interested whether there are alternatives to R to do so, but I'm not seeing anything viable from you either.

Comment: ..cont.: Please expand with actual code on how he "can use the mysql spatial index" for such a clustering application.

Comment: I don't think the OP is looking to find places within a certain rectangle. He's looking into *clustering* arbitrary points in *clusters*. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zqKFH7WNmfE

Comment: Here is what the OP is asking this time: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17947774/476 This discussion is leading nowhere. The OP has to decide whether he needs actual cluster analysis or grid buckets.

Comment: So what do comments on another question have to do with this question? And maybe you not understanding what I'm writing is the problem here.

Comment: Let's not. You're talking about spatial queries and types of indexes to improve their performance. I'm talking about cluster detection and analysis, which *I think* the OP is talking about. Peace out.